# I need to compare a list of patterns specified in a file to another file and report only the matching part of column containing pattern

Tags: linux, search, awk, grep

I need to compare a list of strings specified in a file (file1) to another file (file2) and report only the matching part of column containing string and one other column using linux

Below is an example:

File containing strings to be searched -file 1 is as below

```
Name

Laura

Caroline

Chan

Carol
```

File to be searched - file2:

```
Name                        Title             Salary 

George                     Research fellow      48000

Vanesse, Laura , Robert    Graduate student     20000

Patrick, Simon             Data Analyst         58000

Caroline              Administrative assistant  52000

Allison, Treacey, Chan   Research Technician    60000

Carol, John                Lab Managers         70000
```

Below is the required output(name column containing only matched entries (please note this column has comma separated values in some rows but I need only matched entries of the name column in my output) and salary column alone) :

```
Name        Salary

Laura       20000

Caroline    52000

Chan        60000
```

I want to perform this task using linux commands. Can this be done using linux grep/awk command?

Additional notes on requirement:

Partial matches: not OK
Spaces between my columns: tabs

Thanks!

Comment: grep -o but I also need the column salary for matching entries

Comment: Never use the word "pattern" as it's ambiguous. Replace the word "pattern" in your question with either "string" or "regexp" (whichever type of match it is you want) and add whether or not partial matches are OK and include those in your example (e.g. Carol in one file and Caroline in the other). Also include cases where the text you want to find appears in the wrong column, if such a thing can happen. Finally - what are the spaces between your columns: tabs or sequence of bank chars? If that latter how can you tell where one column ends and the next begins?

Answer (score 0):

awk is a good tool for this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "name salary"} FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} {for (name in a) if ($0~name) print name,$NF}' file1 file2
name salary
Laura 20000
Caroline 52000
Chan 60000
```

#### How it works

- `BEGIN{print "name salary"}`

  This prints out the header
- `FNR==NR{a[$1]; next}`

  While reading the first file, this saves each name as a key in associative array `a`.  This then skips the rest of the commands and jumps to the `next` line.
- `for (name in a) if ($0~name) print name,$NF`

  If we get here, we are reading the second file.  If any `name` in array `a` is found in the input line, `$0`, then we print that name and the last field on the line, denoted `$NF`.

#### Matching whole names only

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "name salary"} FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} {n=NF; for (name in a) for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {if ($i~("^"name",?$")) print name,$NF; if ($i~/,/)n=i+1}}' file1 file2
```

Comment: That would fail given various inputs due to the partial regexp match, e.g. it'd match Carol with Caroline in the Name field or even match Ed with Further Education in the Title.

Answer (score 0):

after fixing the type on your names file

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} 
              {n=gsub(/,/,",");
               for(i=1;i<=n+1;i++) if($i in a) print $i,$NF }' file1 file2

Laura 20000
Caroline 52000
Chan 60000
```

checks only the names in each record, not the titles.

Comment: That would fail to find Treacey or Robert if they appeared in file1.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ambiguity in your question but this MAY be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { print $1, $NF; next }
NR==FNR {
    n = split($0,names,/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/)
    sub(/[[:space:]].*/,"",names[n])
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        #print "<" names[i] ">"
        name2sal[names[i]] = $NF
    }
    next
}
$1 in name2sal { print $1, name2sal[$1] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1 | column -t
Name      Salary
Laura     20000
Caroline  52000
Chan      60000
```